# Python 2.7 for loop splitting string when not wanted

Tags: python-2.7

Having a problem with a script function that is splitting a string inside a for loop when I don't want it to.

```
def loop_names(DNS_NAMES):
print DNS_NAMES
for host in DNS_NAMES:
    print host
```

The first print statement will return `google.com`
The second print statement returns [string characters returned on separate lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1A1a.png)

Unfortunately this breaks the post request thats trying to use the `host` value as a url target.

When I check data types both pre and post loop they come back as string.

Comment: `DNS_NAMES` is clearly a string. Looping over it would produce the next character from that string on each iteration. May be you should revise how you pass arguments to `loop_names` when you call it?..

Comment: Good point. Ill look at other ways of passing arguments. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I'd guess you want `DNS_NAMES` to be a list or tuple of strings, rather than a single string. If you want to call the function with just a single host, you want to pass a one-element list or tuple.

Comment: ...you may check it with `isinstance` although some may argue that this is not a "good style"..